# Gnuplot saving many images

Tags: c++, c, png, gnuplot

I want to write result of gnuplot operation to png file and this succeedes, but I need to generate about 100 png files and here I am running into problem since I receive an error that "maximum number of temporary files gnuplot is 27". When I use method remove_tmpfiles() all images are generated properly but about 20-30 of them are not openable. This mistake does not appear when I save only recommended 27 images.

```
Gnuplot::set_GNUPlotPath( GNUPLOT_PATH );
Gnuplot *main_plot = new Gnuplot;    
main_plot->cmd("set terminal pngcairo\n");
for(int j=0; j<100;j++)
{   
 rysuj_wagi(j, main_plot);  
 if(j%25 == 0) main_plot->remove_tmpfiles(); 
} 


    void rysuj_wagi(int numer, Gnuplot * main_plot)
{
  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss <<"set output 'waga" << numer<<".png'";
  string output = oss.str();
  cout<<output;
  main_plot->cmd(output); 
  main_plot->set_grid(); 
  main_plot->set_xrange(-5,5);
  main_plot->set_yrange(-5,5);
  main_plot->set_style( "linespoints" );
  main_plot->set_pointsize( 1.0 );  
  vector<double> x, y;
  x.push_back(0); 
  y.push_back(0);
  x.push_back(punktyWagX[numer]);
  y.push_back(punktyWagY[numer]);
  main_plot->reset_plot();
  main_plot->plot_xy(x, y); 
}
```

Do you happen to know the way out?

Comment: Which files cannot be opened? Try adding `main_plot->cmd("set output");` at the end of your function `rysuj_wagi`. Gnuplot finalizes an output file only when a new `set output 'filename'` is encountered. Maybe that interferes with the `remove_tmpfiles()`. To avoid that, sending a `set output` (yes, without filename) may help.

Comment: It always did not create about last 10 images for every 25. Your solution works but cases when I remove temp_files() so about 4 on 100 are not openable. My thought was that it was removing temp_file too quickly so I forced it to sleep for a while for(int j=0; j<100;j++)
{   
 rysuj_wagi(j, main_plot); 
 if(j== 25 || j == 50 || j == 75) {
  Sleep(1000);
  main_plot->remove_tmpfiles(); 
 }  
} and this works as well. Thanks for effort.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using this API: http://jfi.uchicago.edu/~tcaswell/track_doc/classgnuplot_1_1Gnuplot.html

Have you tried something like this:

```
main_plot->cmd("set terminal pngcairo\n");         
//some setting of YOUR_FILENAME
main_plot->cmd("set output 'YOUR_FILENAME'\n");
main_plot->cmd("replot\n");
```

You could hopefully avoid the temp files all together.